# Angular Bootstrap Text Carousel Vertical Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, news-ticker

I have an Angular Bootstrap text carousel, How can I use the same code but with vertical scroll instead? Here's a working (horizontal scroll) [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wayne_james/1Lutc1fa/1/#).

This is what I have at the minute.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="textCarousel" class="row">
  <div id="group-news-carousel">
    <div ng-controller="groupNewsController" id="text-carousel">
      <h2>Group News</h2>
      <carousel interval="interval">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
          {{slide.text}}
        </slide>
      </carousel>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 290px;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel-inner > .item {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
  -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  line-height: 1;
}
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.next,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
}
.carousel-inner > .active,
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  display: block;
}
.carousel-inner > .active {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
  left: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 100%;
}
.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 15%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001)));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
}
.carousel-control.right {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
}
.carousel-control:hover,
.carousel-control:focus {
  outline: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -10px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: serif;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev:before {
  content: '\2039';
}
.carousel-control .icon-next:before {
  content: '\203a';
}
.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 -30%;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border: 4px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transition: ease 0.7s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: ease 0.7s;
}
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.carousel-caption .btn {
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about verticle navigation as well with the text to slide to top instead of left?

Comment: Yeah, so instead of the text scrolling right-left, it scrolls bottom-top.

Comment: Added an answer. Please check and if helped then do mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes in the css. For the bottom to top scroll:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
  -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  top: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  top: 0;
}
```

For the verticle navigation:

```
.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 10%;
    z-index: 15;
    width: 10%;
    height:60%;
    margin: 0 -30%;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I think you should be good to go. Hope this helps.